# Como usar o TFormatSettings no Delphi 10 Tokyo?

Tags: delphi, datetime, formatação

Como faço para setar as configurações regionais de data, hora, separador decimal, separador de milhar, no Delphi 10 Tokyo? Anteriormente, no Delphi 7, existiam as variáveis globais de sistema. Em versões mais novas criaram o record `TFormatSettings`, porém aparentemente não está surtindo efeito as alterações que estou fazendo.

Exemplo: Estou rodando meu programa em um PC em que a data e hora locais estão no formato americano, ou seja, 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM' (mês invertido e 12 horas + AM/PM). Eu quero que minha aplicação fique no padrão brasileiro, ou seja, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" (24 horas).

Como aplicar essa alteração nas minhas configurações locais usando o `TFormatSettings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é um exemplo de como utilizo

```
procedure FillFormatSettings(var FSettings: TFormatSettings);
begin
{$IFNDEF VER180}
FSettings:=TFormatSettings.Create('pt-BR');
{$ENDIF}
FSettings.DateSeparator:=#47;
FSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
FSettings.TimeSeparator:=#58;
FSettings.LongTimeFormat:='hh:nn:ss';
FSettings.ShortTimeFormat:='hh:nn';
end;

function DateTimeToStrBrazilian(DateTime: TDateTime): String;
var
  FmtSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
FillFormatSettings(FmtSettings);
Result:=DateToStr(DateTime, FmtSettings)+' '+TimeToStr(DateTime, FmtSettings)
end;
```

Nas novas versões do Delphi você precisa instanciar uma variável do tipo `TFormatSettings`, configurá-la e então utilizar no método que deseja como por exemplo no `DateToStr(Data, VariavelFormatSettings)`

**EDITADO**

Para mudar a configuração global pode ser utilizada a variável global do delphi `FormatSettings` que pertence à `System.SysUtils`.

Exemplo:

```
FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator:=#47;
FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
```

Comment: Obrigado Matheus. Porém, nas versões antigas do Delphi, uma vez setadas as configurações globais não era mais necessário passar minha formatação personalizada para nada, tal como você mostrou em seu `DateToStr(Data, VariavelFormatSettings)`. Isso não é mais possível nas versões atuais do Delphi?

Comment: Claro, é possível sim, apenas use a variável global do delphi `FormatSettings` ela pertence à `System.SysUtils`. Então poderia fazer mais ou menos assim, por exemplo,`FormatSettings.DateSeparator`

Comment: Realmente você tem razão. Eu estava tentando fazer a criação da variável e basta apenas setar o record `TFormatSettings` diretamente sem criar nada. Obrigado!